# $x_0$ is a solution to normalized system, show that $S = x_0 + Null(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given: Matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $b \in R^m$.

> The corresponding normalized system is: $A^TAx = A^Tb$

If $x_0$ is a solution to the normalized system, show that $$S = x_0 + \operatorname{Null}(A) = \{x_0 + y | y \in \operatorname{Null}(A)\}$$ is the set of the solutions of the normalized system.

Well, I know that $\operatorname{Null}(A^TA) = \operatorname{Null}(A^T)$, and I believe that number of solutions of the normalized system is $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{Null}(A^TA)) = n - \operatorname{rank}(A^TA) = n - \operatorname{rank}(A^T) = n - \operatorname{rank}(A)$.

**But I still don't know how to prove that:**

- **Every vector in $S$ is a solution to the normalized system**
- **Every $s$ solution to the normalized system is in $S$**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First assume $s \in S$, then there's an $y\in \operatorname{Null}A$ such that $s=x_0+y$.
Then $$A^TAs = A^TAx_0 + A^TAy = A^Tb + A^T0 = A^Tb$$

Secondly if $x$ is a solution, then $$x = x_0 + (x-x_0)$$

So$$A^Tb = A^TAx = A^TA(x_0 + (x - x_0)) = A^Tb + A^TA(x-x_0)$$ thus
$$A^TA(x-x_0) = 0.$$ Conclude by noting that this means  $x-x_0 \in \operatorname{Null} A$.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew.

Comment: Sure thing. The typical 'do nothing by adding and subtracting something' 'trick'  is usually worth trying!